# Create a grid and setting colors from an array

Tags: javascript, grid-layout, phaser-framework

I need to create a grid from an array of 250 colors for a colorpicker.
Grid layout example:

```
xxxxx 
xxxxx 
xxxxx
...
```

- What already **works**: Creating a grid and setting the colors for the buttons.
- What **doesn't** work: The colors are **not** in the **correct** **order**.

Phaser 3 / JavaScript code:

```
const arrColors = [ '0xF44336', '0xFFEBEE', '0xFFCDD2', '0xEF9A9A', '0xE57373', '0xEF5350', '0xE53935', '0xD32F2F', '0xC62828', '0xB71C1C', '0xFF8A80', '0xFF5252', '0xFF1744', '0xD50000', '0xFCE4EC', '0xF8BBD0', '0xF48FB1', '0xF06292']; 
// Array shortened for readability

for(let xGrid = 1; xGrid < 6; xGrid++) {
    for(let yGrid = 1; yGrid < 12; yGrid++) {
        this.add.sprite( xGrid * 100, yGrid * 100, 'button-color').setTint(arrColors[xGrid+yGrid])
    }
 }
```

How to set the colors in the predefined order to the buttons on the grid?

Comment: What is the correct order?

Comment: @evolutionxbox The correct order like defined in "arrColors". The first 5 colors should be  to the first 5 buttons and so on.

Comment: Why do you start your loops from 1, instead of 0 since you are working with an array

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the code

- Javascript arrays start at 0, so having the for loops starting at 1
  misses some entries.
- The xGrid value is being incremented by 1 each time, but then just
  added to the yGrid to get the position, it needs to be xGrid*6 so as
  to correctly start on the x row.

  ```
   const arrColors = [ '0xF44336', '0xFFEBEE', '0xFFCDD2', '0xEF9A9A', '0xE57373', '0xEF5350', '0xE53935', '0xD32F2F', '0xC62828', '0xB71C1C', '0xFF8A80', '0xFF5252', '0xFF1744', '0xD50000', '0xFCE4EC', '0xF8BBD0', '0xF48FB1', '0xF06292']; 
   // Array shortened for readability

   for(let xGrid = 0; xGrid < 6; xGrid++) {
       for(let yGrid = 0; yGrid < 12; yGrid++) {
           this.add.sprite( xGrid * 100, yGrid * 100, 'button-color').setTint(arrColors[(xGrid * 6) + yGrid])
       }
    }
  ```